# Castle Windsor resolving the wrong implementation of interface for the MVC area

Tags: model-view-controller, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have an interface in the core project of my solution: IPersonManager, which has two concrete implementations, which belong to their own respective projects.

In my web project there is an MVC area representing both of these projects and there is a framework installer class in each area which registers the person manager class to the interface in each area as follows:

```
 container.Register(AllTypes
                         .FromAssemblyNamed("MySolution.MyProject")
                               .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Manager"))
                               .WithService.DefaultInterface()
                               .Configure(x => x.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest)
            );
```

Following registration, when I GetHandlers on the Kernel for the IPersonManager interface I get the following:

```
{Castle.MicroKernel.IHandler[2]}
[0]: Model: {MySolution.Core.Interfaces.Services.IPersonManager}   
/ {MySolution.Area1.PersonManager} 

[1]: Model: {MySolution.Core.Interfaces.Services.IPersonManager} 
/ {MySolution.Area2.PersonManager}
```

So I can see that both implementations have been registered.

The problem is that when I am in Area2 on the web site, windsor is resolving Area1's implementation of the interface rather than Area2.

It seems as though windsor is just giving me back the one that was registered first. Is there a way to get back the correct implementation based on MVC area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with Patrick's suggestion, here's the code:

```
public class PersonManagerHandlerSelector : IHandlerSelector
{
    public bool HasOpinionAbout(string key, System.Type service)
    {
        return service == typeof (IPersonManager);
    }

    public IHandler SelectHandler(string key, System.Type service, 
                                                         IHandler[] handlers)
    {
        var dataTokens = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.
                                          RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens;
        if (dataTokens.Any())
        {
            var area = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.
                                                   RouteData.DataTokens["area"];

            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(area.ToString())
                       ? handlers.First(x => 
                                     x.ComponentModel.Name.Contains("." + area))
                       : handlers.First();
        }
        return handlers.First();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider an [IHandlerSelector](http://ayende.com/blog/3633/windsor-ihandlerselector) for this.  You can examine the current HTTP request context and "help" windsor decide which implementation to use.